# determining directory and its path in focused window (linux)

Tags: linux, bash, user-interface

so I design quite a few webpages and get quite annoyed with the time to construct the default head title body tags etc, and I have general templates and was wondering how to create a script in bash that could 1. determine the directory open in the focused window and 2. copy whichever template from a template directory I have made so if i want a blank php file with all the basic html tags or an html file with basic required tags it can be copied over effortlessly with a simple shortcut i can map.

i know how to do everything in this except for determining the directory of the open file window(the GUI not the terminal)  and haven't had much luck googling this idea, all help appreciated

Comment: By "open file window" are you speaking of a bash terminal? If so, the command you are looking for is `pwd`. The `$PWD` environment variable can also serve.

Comment: no, sorry I mean the actual GUI window not the terminal. *edited a bit for clarity

Comment: The GUI window is your own program?

Comment: no its the default ubuntu files explorer I would upload a pic except I am unable to due to rep limitations

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tty of a window, and then use that to send a command. I've heard of a tool called "ttyecho" though I've never used it, but supposedly it can be used to send a command to a different pty (another window).

Comment: you have any relevant articles or what the tty stands for? all i tend to get is puTTY or else hearing communication stuff

Comment: Googling "what is tty in linux" provides a plethora of results, and this seems to be a decent result:
[stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)